How to structure an AWS Lambda Python 3 Application - with local and 3rd-party dependencies
Problem Summary
I am an AWS Lambda Python newbie and I am struggling with structuring my application which has local and 3rd-party dependencies. My AWS Python Lambda function is failing to run due to not finding the 'pyathena' package:
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'pyathena'

Current application's structure.
app.py
organization_name_folder
├── configs
│   └── mysql_db_configs.py
├── db
│   └── query_executor.py
├── enums
│   └── mysql_config_prop.py
├── libs
│   └── pyathena

Code packaging.
The code is packaged into a zip file.
zip -r function_name.zip __init__.py \
app.py \
libs \
organization_name_folder

Handler’s configuration
Here is how the function’s handler is configured: app.handler_name
3rd-party installation
Here is how I installed my 3rd party packages: pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target ./libs, which installs the packages into a libs folder.
Imports
import pyathena
from organization_name.folder_path_to_python_file.python_file import ClassName

What I attempted so far:
I attempted those modify the application's imports as follows without luck
import pyathena

import libs.pyathena

My questions

How should I structure my application?
How should I reference my imports?
Does my Lambda configurations sound
Is there any configuration file (such as a json/yaml) need to be included in the code packaging to run correctly?

